# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, js engine: hermes React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, callstack

So I'm new to React Native and I stumbled upon this error while making a guess game... It says `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This is what I have in my App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'
import GameStart from './pages/GameStart';
import GameScreen from './pages/GameScreen';
import GameOver from './pages/GameOver';
import Colors from './constants/colors';

export default function App() {

const [userNumber, setUserNumber] = useState()
const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(true)

const setNumberHandler = (number) => {
  setUserNumber(number);
  setGameOver(false);
}

const gameOverHandler = () => {
  setGameOver(true)
}

let screen = <GameStart setNumberHandler={setNumberHandler} />

if (userNumber) {
 screen = <GameScreen playerGuess={userNumber} gameOverHandler= 
 {gameOverHandler}/>
}

if(gameOver && userNumber) {
  screen = <GameOver />
}

return (
<LinearGradient
  colors={[Colors.tertiary, Colors.secondery]}
  style={styles.container}>
  <ImageBackground
    source={require("./assets/images/background.png")}
    style={styles.container}
    imageStyle={styles.imageStyle}
  >
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {screen}
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ImageBackground>
</LinearGradient>
);
}
```

This is a function that creates a random number

```
const generateRandomNumber = (min, max, exclude) => {
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

if (random === exclude) {
    return generateRandomNumber(min, max, exclude);
} else {
    return random;
 }
}
```

After that I'm initializing the state in the main component, the gameOverHandler() is called when the initials guess is the same as the new guess, and also a function nextGuessHandler() which depending on the direction parameter, increases or decreases the guess to find and match the initial one...

```
let min = 1;
let max = 100;

const initialGuess = generateRandomNumber(1, 100, playerGuess)
const [guess, setGuess] = useState(initialGuess);

useEffect(() => {
    if(guess === playerGuess) {
        gameOverHandler()
    }
}, [guess, playerGuess, gameOverHandler])

    const nextGuessHandler = (direction) => {

    if (
        (direction === "lower" && guess < playerGuess) ||
        (direction === "greater" && guess > playerGuess)
    ) {
        Alert.alert(
            "Don't lie",
            "You know that this is wrong...",
            [{ text: "sorry", style: "cancel" }]
        )
        return;
    }

    if (direction === 'lower') {
        max = guess;
    } else {
        min = guess + 1;
    }
    const newRandom = generateRandomNumber(min, max, playerGuess)
    setGuess(newRandom)
}
```

And at last I have the JSX code

```
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Title>AI's Guess</Title>
        <GuessNumber>{guess}</GuessNumber>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button onClick={nextGuessHandler.bind(this, "greater")}>+</Button>
            <Button onClick={nextGuessHandler.bind(this, "lower")}>-</Button>
        </View>
    </View>
)
```

After the initial guess and the new guess match, the whole application crashes and it gives me the error from above `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, instead of showing the gameOver component when the game is finished, how can I fix this issue, maybe with the useMemo hook?

Comment: Add the code for the gameOverHandler please

Comment: I just added the entire JSX code from my App.js where the gameOverHandler is located.

Comment: What if you force the GameOver screen to load, does it crash then?

Comment: Yes it still crashes...

Comment: Then the problem is on that screen - post the code for that screen please

Comment: I dont have any code on the GameOver screen, its just a simple functional component, that's rendering some text